# Slot Machine Probabilities

Tags: probability, statistics

If there is a slot machine with 4 slots, each with a possibility of being either a cherry, a lemon, or a 7, what is the probability of getting exactly two lemons?

My thinking:

4 slot machine, 3 options: 3*3*3*3 = 81 total options.

getting exactly 2 lemons: 1*1*3*3 = 9

P(LL) = 9/81 = 0.1111

What is wrong with this?

Comment: To get exactly 2 lemons, you need to look at 2 lemons and 2 non-lemons.  and then there are 6 possible orderings of the lemons and the non-lemons.

Comment: You also need to account for the different choice of the two slots in which lemons are observed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation assumes that lemons must be in the first two slots (the $1$s you multiply in) and allows lemons in the last two slots (the $3$s you multiply in), so would accept four lemons and reject 7-7-lemon-lemon.  You should compute the number of ways to choose the two slots for the lemons, then require that the other two slots be non-lemons.

Comment: So instead the probability is 4/81?

Comment: No, you missed the number of places the lemons can go.  That is the chance the first two are lemons and the others are non-lemons.  This fixes the four lemons part, but not the 7-7-lemon-lemon part.

Comment: Ok. So if the possibilities for that are {(L,L,L^c,L^c),(L,L^c,L,L^c),(L,L^c,L^c,L),(L^c,L,L^c,L),(L^c,L,L,L^c)} , 5 possibilites. would 5 be multiplied by 4/81?

Comment: It should be six. You have to choose two slots out of four, and ${4 \choose 2}=6$, so you missed one-where the two lemons are last.  Yes, you multiply.

Comment: So I would have to divide by the total number of slot face possibilities for lemon and non-lemon? Which would be 11? So the probability is 0.5454?

Comment: No, the overall number of possibilities is $3^4=81$ as you said at the start.  We are just trying to count how many of those have exactly two lemons.

Comment: So because there is 6 ways for this to occur on the slot faces, the probability of it occurring in one orientation is multiplied by 6. So the probability is 0.2963.

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably gathered by now from the other answers and comments, there are ${4\choose2}=6$ ways to place the lemons (L's) on the four slots.  And then the two remaining slots can either be Cherry or Seven. The table below shows why then you would multiply $6\times4=24$ to get the total arrangements.

The Lemon-only arrangements are...
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
\text{L-L-x-x} & \text{L-x-L-x} & \text{...}& \text{...}& \text{...} & \text{x-x-L-L} 
\end{array}
$$
So the total arrangements with exactly 2 Lemons would be.
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
\text{L-L-C-C} & \text{L-C-L-C} & \text{...}& \text{...}& \text{...} & \text{...} \\
\hline
\text{L-L-C-7} & \text{...} & \text{...} & \text{...} & \text{...} & \text{...} \\
\hline
\text{L-L-7-C} & \text{...} & \text{...} & \text{...} & \text{...} & \text{...} \\
\hline
\text{L-L-7-7} & \text{...} & \text{...} & \text{...} & \text{...}& \text{7-7-L-L} \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: this table is 6x5.